# Dynamically populate select options with nested JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

**What i want to achieve**

I have got one static select html options, these options do not change but will determine what the other select boxes output.

```
<select id="firstselectbox">
<option value="first">This is the first</option>
<option value="second">This is the second</option>
<option value="third">This is the third</option>
<option value="fourth">This is the fourth</option>
<option value="fifth">This is the fifth</option>
</select>
```

**Currently, the code i have written doesnt want to output the following:**

Select 1: option selected `first`

Select 2: checks jSon file, finds first and all of the nodes (second layer) and list them. When a user selects that.

Select 3: displays the third layer

Please note the `*` is the option selected below - select 1 is static and select 2 and 3 are dynamic.

```
Select 1    Select 2    Select 3
first*      London      Famous Famous
second      Jersey      London Famous
third       North*  
fourth      South East  
fifth       South West  
sixth
```

**What have i done so far**

```
var datajson = {"first":[{"jesery":[{"id":"jesery","name":"Jesery","jesery":[{"id":"famous","name":"Famous Famous"},{"id":"distance","name":"Distance"}]}],"dontknow":[{"id":"dontknow","name":"Dont Know"}]}],"second":[{"london":[{"id":"london","name":"London","london":[{"id":"f2f","name":"London Famous"},{"id":"famous","name":"Famous Famous"},{"id":"distance","name":"Distance"}]}]}],"third":[{"london":[{"id":"london","name":"London","london":[{"id":"f2f","name":"London Famous"},{"id":"famous","name":"Famous Famous"},{"id":"distance","name":"Distance"}]}],"north":[{"id":"north","name":"North","north":[{"id":"f2f","name":"London Famous"},{"id":"famous","name":"Famous Famous"},{"id":"distance","name":"Distance"}]}]}],"forth":[{"north":[{"id":"north","name":"North","north":[{"id":"f2f","name":"London Famous"},{"id":"famous","name":"Famous Famous"},{"id":"distance","name":"Distance"}]}],"dontknow":[{"id":"dontknow","name":"Dont Know"}]}],"fifth":[{"london":[{"id":"london","name":"London","london":[{"id":"f2f","name":"London Famous"},{"id":"famous","name":"Famous Famous"},{"id":"distance","name":"Distance"}]}],"southeast":[{"id":"southeast","name":"South East","southeast":[{"id":"distance","name":"Distance"}]}]}]}

$("#firstselectbox").on('change', function() {
     $("select#firstselectbox").html('');
        var locations = datajson[$(this).val()];
        var locationString = '';
     $.each(locations, function(i, item) {

        console.log(locations[i]);

         locationString += '<option id="'+ locations[i].id + '" value="' + locations[i].id + '">'  + locations[i].name + '</option>';
     });
    $('#secondselectbox').html(locationString);
});
```

**Issue?**

The following code is `locationString += '<option id="'+ locations[i].id + '" value="' + locations[i].id + '">'  + locations[i].name + '</option>';` is outputting `unidentified`.

However `console.log(locations[i]);` is outputting the array that that is selected from the static select box (first, second etc..). However, trying to separate that out seems to fail.

The current code is outputting `unidentified`.

Comment: You should fix first your json structure...it seems to be messy

Comment: @RobertRozas any recommendations on what would be the ideal json file for my use case?

Comment: You want basically select `This is the first` in the first select and populate the second with `{"id":"famous","name":"Famous Famous"},{"id":"distance","name":"Distance"}`..is that ok??

Comment: @RobertRozas Yes but what about the third layer? and how am i going to be linking the static element with the second layer? (if that makes sense)

Comment: When we reach the third layer i get lost...what is that...i just see two(like in my example)...if my example was ok, i can work with it...just let me know

Answer (score 0):

Use unobtrusive JavaScript so you won't have to hunt bugs like this one:

```
$('#secondselectbox').empty()

$.each(locations, function(i, item) {
  $("<option/>",{id:locations[i].id, value:locations[i].id, text:locations[i].name})
  .appendTo('#secondselectbox')
})
```

Edit: Also there is a problem with your JSON structure. You basically have an array which contains a single object, so when you foreach the array you are at one level lower than where you need to be.

Comment: Thanks but this doesnt answer my question. Your code just outputs an empty append to the second select box.

Comment: Hi Bobby, Thanks for that - can you please provide me an example of one element which is proper JSON - so i can pin point where i am going wrong.